# error: invalid instruction operand (on .ENDW)

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32, masm32

```
include irvine32.inc

.data
i dword 0
j dword 0
x dword 0
reservedseats byte 45 dup(0)
seats dword 45

.code
main proc

xor eax,eax
xor ecx,ecx
xor ebx,ebx
.while(i<45)
xor edx, edx
mov edx, i
.if([reservedseats+edx]==0)
    mov ebx,i
    mov x,ebx
    push ecx
    .while(j<seats)
    mov reservedseats,1
        inc i

    inc j
    .endw
    pop ecx
    jmp next
.endif


inc i
.endw
next:

 exit 
 main endp
 end main
```

This is an assembly (masm32) code.

I am working on assembly project seat reservation. I am trying to convert c++ code to assembly. this progrm will print seats given by users and if user wants to reserve seat again he will skip seats that are already reserved.

It gives me an error. The error(invalid instruction) is on first `.endw` after `inc j`.

Comment: I am guessing maybe `.while(j<seats)` is invalid because both are in memory.  Try whether `.while(j<45)` works. You should really avoid using the silly high-level directives, especially if you don't know what code they will generate exactly.

Comment: Re-write that block with pure assembly from `.while` to `.endw` : `mov ecx,seats` , `reserved:` , `cmp j,ecx` , `jae endblock` , `mov reservedseats,1` , `inc i` , `inc j` , `jmp reserved` , `endblock:`.

Comment: Please read [how do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the part "Introduce the problem before you post any code".

Comment: If you have solved the problem, you should answer your own question, explain what you did, and include the updated code.